# What package name should I use for a Cyanogenmod theme?

Tags: apk, cyanogenmod, themes

I want to make cm11 theme.

But one problem: package name.

How does it work? Dialer package has com.android.dialer, so my package could have name eu.mikroskeem.colormelt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about CM themes in particular, but Android app package names are based on Java packages, which means they have to start with a web domain you own, in big-endian order. That is, if and only if you own the domain `mikroskeem.eu`, you can use any package name starting `eu.mikroskeem.`

There's no way to enforce this convention, but following it makes sure that package names are unique.

Comment: I have domain `mikroskeem.eu`, but I'm just curious if I don't own this domain name, then I can't use it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.